# Prime ideals in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, abstract-algebra

Let $k$ a field. Let $f$ be the ring injective homomorphism

$$ f:k[x] \rightarrow k[x,y]/(xy-1)$$

obtained as the composition of the inclusion $k[x] \subset k[x,y]$ and the natural projection map $ f:k[x,y] \rightarrow k[x,y]/(xy-1)$.

> Prove that there isn't any prime ideal in the ring $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ whose contraction in $k[x]$ is the prime ideal $(x)$.
>
> Is there any prime ideal in $k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ whose contraction is $(x-1)$?

Thanks! :)

Comment: It looks like you're asking two different questions.

Comment: Do you know anything about localizations of rings?

Comment: yes, they're two different questions. Is an execise of my weekly problem set.

Comment: I have studied a little about localizations of rings

Comment: Why need localization here? The form of the (prime) ideals in a quotient ring should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ be a prime ideal in $k[x,y]$.

If $xy-1,x\in P$ then $1\in P$, contradiction.

If $xy-1,x-1\in P$ then $y-1\in P$, so we can take $P=(x-1,y-1)$. (Note that $xy-1\in(x-1,y-1)$.)

Answer (score 6):

HINT:

$k[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is naturally isomorphic to the ring of fractions $k[x][\frac{1}{x}] = S^{-1}\ k[x]$, where $S= \{1,x,x^2, \ldots\}$.

Comment: $S$ is a PID, right? Is it also an euclidean domain?

Comment: @AguirreK : Yes, the localization of a PID is a again a PID. I am not sure if the above is a Euclidean domain.